# Defining functions with Dummy variables

Tags: functions

I have defined a functional F, whose argument are product of functions: F[ f[x] g[x] h[x]...]

I need x to be a "dummy variable". That is, I need Mathematica to understand that, for example,

F[ f[x] g[x] ] - F[ f[y] g[y] ] =0

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: You can use [`TagSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSet.html). 

`F /: F[f[x_] g[x_]] - F[f[y_] g[y_]] = 0;` 

Then 

`F[f[z] g[z]] - F[f[t] g[t]] + c` evaluates to 

`c`

Comment: What is the difference between `x` being a dummy variable and the whole `f[x] g[x]` being a dummy variable ?

Comment: thanks Bob:  what you suggest is what I have been doing so far. The problem is that I have terms with different number of functions inside F : F[ h1[x] h2[]x] h3[x]....hn[x]].  Using TagSet I have to do it case by case...

Answer (score 1):

Use [`TagSet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSet.html)

```
ClearAll[F]

F /: F[arg1__] - F[arg2__] /;
   (Head[arg1] === Head[arg2] === Times &&
     Length@Union[List @@@ List @@ arg1] ==
      Length@Union[List @@@ List @@ arg2] == 1&&
     (Head /@ List @@ arg1) === (Head /@ List @@ arg2)) = 0;
```

The number of factors can vary

```
F[f[x] g[x]] - F[f[y] g[y]]

(* 0 *)

F[f[x] g[x] h[x]] - F[f[y] g[y] h[y]]

(* 0 *)

F[f[x] g[x] h[x] k[x]] - F[f[y] g[y] h[y] k[y]]

(* 0 *)
```

The order of the arguments' factors does not matter

```
F[f[x] g[x] h[x]] - F[f[y] h[y] g[y]]

(* 0 *)
```

**EDIT:** The extension of the problem given in your comment, "I would like `2*F[h[x] k[x]] - F[h[y] k[y]]` to give `F[h[x] k[x]]`", is not readily handled by `TagSet` since `F` would be buried too deeply in the more general expression.  Using an alternative approach

```
ClearAll[F]

simplifyF[expr_] := Module[{var, rules},
  vars = Cases[expr,
     F[arg_?(Head[#] === Times &&
           Length@Union[List @@@ List @@ #] == 1 &)] :>
      (List @@ arg)[[1, 1]], Infinity] // Union;
  rules = Thread[Rest[vars] -> First[vars]];
  expr /. F[
     arg_?(Head[#] === Times &&
         Length@Union[List @@@ List @@ #] == 1 &)] :>
    (F[arg] /. rules)]

testExpression = {F[f[x] g[x]] - F[f[y] g[y]],
   F[f[x] g[x] h[x]] - F[f[y] g[y] h[y]],
   F[f[x] g[x] h[x] k[x]] - F[f[y] g[y] h[y] k[y]],
   F[f[x] g[x] h[x]] - F[f[y] h[y] g[y]],
   2*F[h[x] k[x]] - F[h[y] k[y]],
   7*F[h[x] k[x]] - 5 F[h[y] k[y]]};

simplifyF@testExpression

(* {0, 0, 0, 0, F[h[x] k[x]], 2 F[h[x] k[x]]} *)
```

Comment: wow, this seems to work. One little extra feature. I would like 

2*F[h[x] k[x]] - F[h[y] k[y]] to give F[h[x] k[x]].  

Your formula does not seem to give that. 
Thanks!

Comment: @MaxB - See edit.

Comment: This is what I needed ! Thanks!

Now, for my next application I need 

F[ h[x] k[y] G[x,y] = F[ h[w] k[z] G[w,z] ]

the same logic but with 2 dummy variables. I am trying to work it out myself following your idea.... but I am definitely not an expert!

Comment: @MaxB - Do not ask new questions in comments. Post a new question. Note that there is a syntax error in your comment.

Comment: thanks! (& sorry for the syntax). I will try to work out myself the second case.